# How to use tm_map on large corpora without a memory error?

Tags: r, memory-management, tm

I´m trying to do some text mining using the **tm** package. So I create a `corpus` from a string vector. And then I use `tolower`, to remove all capital letters, which results in an error.

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(string_vector))   
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower) # Makes all words lower case

Error in mcfork() :
  unable to fork, possible reason: Cannot allocate memory
```

The string vector I´m using to create the corpus has 5621 rows, the longest string has 4590 characters.
I already played around and removed every object from memory that is not vital to that command using `rm(list=ls())`. But it makes no difference.

I´m running it on a server with 32GB RAM:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

How can I fix this, or is my server just not strong enough?

Comment: Try shrinking your vector until you can get it to work. Then you might discovery your memory limit, if that's the problem. If you can't get it to work with a small subset of your big vector, update your question so your error can be reproduced by others: include a sample of your data and correct code (there's a mis-match in your current code: corpus  != corpus_comments).

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by setting the additional parameter:

'lazy=T' in tm_map

So, your call to tm_map would read:

```
tm_map(corpus, tolower, lazy=T)
```